# How to start a thread that is defined in a private inner class?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, inner-classes

I found this example of how to read from a Bluetooth socket using a separate read thread on [the Android developer website](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection).  The read thread is defined in the private inner class "ConnectedThread".

```
class MyBluetoothService(
        // handler that gets info from Bluetooth service
        private val handler: Handler) {

    private inner class ConnectedThread(private val mmSocket: BluetoothSocket) : Thread() {

        private val mmInStream: InputStream = mmSocket.inputStream
        private val mmOutStream: OutputStream = mmSocket.outputStream
        private val mmBuffer: ByteArray = ByteArray(1024) // mmBuffer store for the stream

        override fun run() {
            var numBytes: Int // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
            while (true) {
                // Read from the InputStream.
                numBytes = try {
                    mmInStream.read(mmBuffer)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e)
                    break
                }

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                val readMsg = handler.obtainMessage(
                        MESSAGE_READ, numBytes, -1,
                        mmBuffer)
                readMsg.sendToTarget()
            }
        }
 //Other functions like write, cancel that I omitted from this example

}
```

So I added a function in MyBluetoothService to start the read thread:

```
 @JvmStatic
fun read(){
val reader = ConnectedThread(myBluetoothSocket)
Reader.start()
}
```

But this gives an immediate error:

> Constructor of inner class ConnectedThread can be called only with
>   receiver of containing class

How should I start the thread from the example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ConnectedThread` is an inner class of `MyBluetoothService` so it can't be instantiated outside an instance of `MyBluetoothService`.

Change it like this (remove `private inner`):

```
class ConnectedThread(private val mmSocket: BluetoothSocket) : Thread() {
```

You'll have to get access to the service some other way, or alternatively create a factory method in your service that instantiates the thread and returns that.

Comment: But your function is static, so it has no instance of the service.

Comment: I tested it, and this is true.  Thank you.